# Как сделать apply, а потом OK в intellij idea быстро?

Tags: intellij-idea

Как сделать apply, а потом OK в `intellij idea` быстро?

Если воспользоваться `ctrl+alt+s`, то откроется окно с настройками. Необходимо когда настройки будут изменены, их применить, а потом нажать ок. Нужно применить настройки и нажать кнопки с помощью какой либо комбинации клавиш. Могу выложить скрины, или набросать нехитрый алгоритм, если что-то непонятно, мало ли...

Comment: Какой apply? О каком диалоге идет речь?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov О том который есть на десятке окон и надо просто принять изменения и закрыть окно с помощью ок.

Comment: @Александр Плющев Правильно заданный вопрос, повышает шанс быть услышанным. Кто будет искать магический шар, что-бы ответить на твой вопрос?

Comment: @Владимир безспорно повышает! Но если человек не может понять абсолютно простой вещи, то ему не следует тогда задумываться и стоит пройти дальше.

Comment: Уважаемый @АлександрПлющев, если вы при поиске пользовались "тот который есть на десятке окон", то гугл наверное всё таки вам помог. Он занял ваше драгоценное время и вы до сих пор анализируете результаты поиска. Когда закончите, потратьте ещё пару минут и отредаактируйте вопрос.

Comment: Хм. `Могу выложить скрины, или набросать нехитрый алгоритм, если что-то непонятно, мало ли`: выкладывайте.